# How to stop an animation from looping

Tags: unity, animation

I want to make Unity play a squish animation when the player hits the ground, but only once, until the player jumps and hits the ground again, although Unity its constantly detecting that the player is on the ground and keeps playing the squish animation over and over again, only jumping stops it cause the condition to play the animation is if the player is on the ground. (loop already disabled)
How I can possibly solve this?

```
 if (isGrounded == true)
        anim.SetTrigger("EnterGround");
```

Comment: btw, you can omit `== true` and the behavior won't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store previous value of `isGrounded`. Change your code to this:

```
if (isGrounded && !wasGrounded) OnLanding ();
wasGrounded = isGrounded;
```

where `wasGrounded` is a boolean field and `OnLanding` is a method where you for example trigger animation.